# Get index of a 1 in a bitarray?

Tags: c#, algorithm, bitarray

Friends, who know how can I get an index of a 1  in a Bitarray and push it to an array. some functions or something else

I have an Uint16 , here I want to read bits from this variable and get indexes of 1 and put it to an array or list

Comment: are there negative bits?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I mean how to get index of 1 in a Bitarray, maybe there is some function indexof or something else, I could not find

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) In any specific position? Or just any *activated* bit?

Comment: Please, provide *examples*, e.g. imagine that you have `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]` bit array, what is the required outcome?

Comment: so as an example { for instance I have an array of bits [true, false, false, false,true] or [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] how to get indexof(true) or indexof(1)

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1, prepare your BitArray:

```
 var bits = new BitArray (new[] { false, true, false, false, true, false, false });
```

Step 2, change it to form for you understandable (List, 1=true, 0=false)

```
 var list = bits.Cast<bool> ().Select (x => x ? 1 : 0).ToList ();
```

Step 3, now you can use `IndexOf` which you already know

```
 int index = list.IndexOf (1); // index=1, it looks from left ot right
```

If you want to search form right to left, use `Reverse()` method on your list.

It is not optimal solution, but I think it is most easy to understand for you.

**EDIT:**

```
var bits = new BitArray (new[] { false, true, false, false, true, false, false });

var bitsWithIndex = bits.Cast<bool> () // we need to use Cast because BitArray does not provide generic IEnumerable
                        .Select ((bit, index) => new { Bit = bit, Index = index}); // projection, we will save bit indices

// now we will get indices of all true(1) bits [from left to right]
var indices = bitsWithIndex.Where (x => x.Bit == true).Select (x => x.Index).ToArray ();
```

Comment: But in case if I want to add these indexes in array?

Comment: YOU HELPED ME SO MUCH) Thank you

Comment: but one more question, is this an optimal solution?

Comment: @RadikHarutyunyan: no, but it is enough. Can you see the ✓ sign near my answer? Click on it :D

Answer (score 0):

You query each position of the bitarray and report the indexes. You could use simple `for` loop and accumulate your true indexes in a List - I choose linq, looks nices:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

public static IEnumerable<int> GetTrueIndexes(BitArray arr)
{
    if (arr != null)        
        return Enumerable.Range(0,arr.Count).Where( idx => arr.Get(idx));

    return new int[0];
}


public static void Main()
{
    BitArray b = new BitArray(
        "100101010000101"
        .Select(c => c == '0' ? false : true )
        .ToArray());

    var trueIndexes =  GetTrueIndexes(b);       

    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",trueIndexes)); 
}
```

Output:

0, 3, 5, 7, 12, 14

Answer (score 0):

You have an UInt16, you need to read indexes of bit 1 then:

```
List<int> GetIndexes(int number) 
{
     var result = new List<int>();
     var index = 0;
     while (number > 0) 
     {
         if (number & 1) 
         {
              result.Add(index);
         } 
         index ++;
         number >= 1;
     }

     return result;
}
```

Comment: hmm but in case of boolens how can I get indexes for true?